# Advanced Terminal Emulation

Tags: bash, development

Would there be a way to emulate the Desktop as a Terminal i.e. XTerm, so you can type in bash on the desktop?

I want some form of window manager that does that exactly.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean to type bash commands on the desktop you can use the [guake terminal](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/guake/).

[image: Screenshot of guake]

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any window manager with this feature, but you can try YaKuake (for KDE) or Tilda (for Gnome), drop-down console which is always accesible on your desktop..

Comment: People never mention Stjerm which is sad. It's like YaKuake, Tilda or Guake just with verly low footprint. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

I use the terminal for [Screenlets](http://screenlets.org/index.php/Screenshots)

You can make a terminal that is transparent without a border that does not move, so it is just like a part of your desktop.

1. Install Screenlets from software center

   [image: Install via the software center]
2. Download the Terminal Screenlet from
   http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Terminal+Screenlet?content=74844
3. Open up Screenlets and Click *Install* and select the downloaded terminal Screenlet package to install.

[image]
4. Click on *Terminal* and then on *Launch/Add* to add new terminal

5.Right click in the terminal => go to Properties => Options to get to the options to style the terminal, the terminal on the right in my picture was styled so the background is transparent(Options *Transparent Terminal* and *Amount*=0) place it where you want, resize it under *Sizing* and remove the border under Sizing => Border Width.

6.To make it start on startup check the box in the Screenlets Manager "Auto start on login"
[image]